# Is the inner automorphism $\phi_g$ the same as $\phi_{g^{-1}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group

In my abstract algebra book, the definition of an inner automorphism is written as:

> Let $G$ be a group, and let $a$ belong to $G$. The function $\phi_a$  defined by $\phi_a(x)= axa^{-1}$ for all $x$ in $G$ is called the inner automorphism of $G$ induced by $a$.

However, in Wikipedia, $\phi_a$ is said to be equal to $a^{-1}xa$.

Are they the same? Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: Please use MathJax, not markup, to format your posts. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742)

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. It’s my first time asking a question here so I’m still learning the ropes.

Comment: Note that you had $\phi_g$ when you really wanted $\phi_a$...

Comment: The definition in your book works best for functions composed right-to-left (the usual), so that $\phi_g\circ\phi_h = \phi_{gh}$. Wikipedia's definition works best for functions composed left-to-right (usually used in suffix, rather than prefix, notation). There was a period of time, around the 60s, when a substantial number of important group theorists were trying to change the "standard" way to write functions so that morphisms would be written on the right (so it would match Ring Theorists, who often do that (so the module morphism property becomes $a(m\phi) = (am)\phi$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, this is whether you act on the left or the right. It's purely a convention thing.  If you 'act on the right', your conjugate of $x$ by $g$ is $g^{-1}xg$, and group actions on a set are $\Omega\times G\to \Omega$ given by $\omega\cdot g$. If you 'act on the left', your conjugate of $x$ by $g$ is $gxg^{-1}$, and group actions on a set are $G\times \Omega\to \Omega$ given by $g(\omega)$.

Because of Euler's $f(x)$ notation for a function $f$ applied to $x$, rather than $xf$ or $(x)f$, people thought it was a good idea to compose functions from the right side to the left, i.e., opposite to how you read in European languages. But in group theory a lot of people compose from left to right. So homomorphisms $\phi$ are written $g\phi$ rather than $\phi(g)$.

It's a complete pain, and the cause of a lot of confusion and errors.

Comment: It was fashionable in the 60s and 70s to write functions on the right, because it matched what ring theorists were doing (if you do modules, that makes every left $R$-module into a bimodule, and homogeneity looks like associativity, $(am)\phi = a(m\phi)$). Hanna Neumann's "Varieties of Groups" is written with suffix function notation, for example... I think it was around then that a lot of group theorists picked it up.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't think I know any finite group theorists who write on the left. It causes great trouble if your conjugate is $x^g$ rather than ${}^g\!x$.

Comment: It may depend on what continent you are in. It is hardly uncommon here in the U.S. to use prefix notation for functions...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The two maps are, in fact, the same. If $\phi_g:x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$ then this means do $g^{-1}$ first, then $x$, then $g$. If $\phi_g:x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ then this means do $g^{-1}$ first, then $x$, then $g$. The meaning is the same, the way of writing it down is different.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Obviously I am not saying that (with the same ordering) $g^{-1}xg$ and $gxg^{-1}$ are the same. I am saying that $gxg^{-1}$ is *not* conjugation by $g$ if one reads left-to-right, and so the fact that $\phi_g$ is defined that way implicitly tells you the reading convention. Otherwise $\phi_g$ is not a homomorphism but an antihomomorphism.

Comment: OK, whatever mate.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez is right. The question "What is the inner automorphism of $x$ by $a$?" has two answers, and they are different maps. Great details on why they both exist, and why some prefer one and some the other, but when I'm writing an answer that goes into a lot of detail, I like to start off with a short and simple answer to the core question. I think that helps the asker, who is confused, by letting them know where all the details are going to end up - though that's probably more a question of writing style than correctness.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I guess I read "Am I missing anything obvious?" as the question, rather than "are these really equal?", since the OP doesn't think they are really, and doesn't understand why the two definitions exist. I guess the difference is didactic. I thought it was clear that it was a convention issue that was the problem, and a small push solves the confusion. There was no deeper misunderstanding about the fact that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ could induce the same map, just that there are two notations. But feel free to upvote the longer answer.

Comment: Ehn, I'd already up voted both answers before I wrote my comment. And i think you are right about the OP - they'll understand the situation based on either one. Like you say, it's a didactic consideration - I read so many other OPs who are having a hard time getting a firm grip on things that for the answers I write here I tend to be much more explicit than when writing other places.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a group. If $g$ is an element of $G$, we can define two functions:
\begin{align}
&\lambda_g:x\in G\mapsto gxg^{-1}\in G, \\
& \rho_g:x\in G\mapsto g^{-1}xg\in G.
\end{align}
In general, these two functions are different. For example, if $G=S_3$, the symmetric group of degree $3$ and $g=(123)$, then
\begin{align}
& \lambda_g((12)) = (123)(12)(123)^{-1}
= (23)
\\
& \rho_g((12)) = (123)^{-1}(12)(123) = (13).
\end{align}
Sometimes, though, $\lambda_g$ and $\rho_g$ do coincide. An extreme case of this is when the group $G$ is abelian — or, more generally, when $g$ is central in $G$ — for then the two functions are just the identity map of $G$.

Now, for all $g$ we have that $(g^{-1})^{-1}=g$, so that you can immediately check that $$\lambda_g=\rho_{g^{-1}}.$$ This means that the *collection* of maps $\{\lambda_g:g\in G\}$ coincides with the collection $\{\rho_g:g\in G\}$.

One can wonder **why** we consider these two maps… Well, let us write $\def\Aut{\operatorname{Aut}}\Aut(G)$ for the group of automorphisms of $G$. The function $$L:g\in G\mapsto \lambda_g\in\Aut(G)$$ is then a morphism of groups. In other words, we have that $L(g)\circ L(h)=L(gh)$ for all choices of $g$ and $h$ in $G$.

What happens with the maps $\rho_g$? Well, the function $$R:g\in G\mapsto\rho_g\in\Aut(G)$$ is *not* a morphism of groups… One can easily check that $$R(g)\circ R(h)=R(hg),$$ and the right hand side here is in general different from $R(gh)$. One way to «fix» this is to change de domain of the map $R$ into the group $G^{\mathrm{op}}$ opposite to $G$: the map $$R:g\in G^{\mathrm{op}}\to\rho_g\in\Aut(G)$$ is now a perfectly civilized morphism of group.

So what is this? Well, a morphism of groups $L:G\to\Aut(G)$ corresponds to an action of $G$ on itself **on the left**: for all $g$ and $h$ in $G$ we let $g$ act on $h$ so that $$g\triangleright h=\lambda_g(h).$$ On the other hand, a morphism of groups $R:G^{\mathrm{op}}\to\Aut(G)$ corresponds to an action of $G$ on itself **on the right**: for all $g$ and $h$ in $G$ we let $g$ act on $h$ so that $$h\triangleleft g=\rho_g(h).$$

People who like their groups acting on the left of things will usually prefer the map $L$, while people who mistakenly prefer their actions on the right usually prefer the map $R$.

Comment: Yeah, the downvotes clearly make a lot of sense... 